elasticsearch consume too much CPU
I did not find the answer in other topics, so I created my own.
Server:

Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-182-generic x86_64)
AMD EPYC 7601 32-Core Processor
16GB RAM

Builded elk stack from docker compose and get a high cpu usage n my server. Can not find the reason
Docker compose
  version: '3.8'
    
    services:
      es01:
        image: es:${SERVICE_NAME}
        container_name: es01
        restart: unless-stopped
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: ./elk-config/elasticsearch/Dockerfile
          args:
            ELK_VERSION: ${ELK_VERSION:-7.13.3}
        networks:
          - ${NETWORK_NAME}
        volumes:
          - "${HOST_PATH}/elk/elasticsearch/es01/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:rw"
        ulimits:
          memlock:
            soft: -1
            hard: -1
        environment:
          - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
          - network.host=0.0.0.0
          - node.name=es01
          - discovery.seed_hosts=es02
          - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02
          - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m"
          - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
          - xpack.license.self_generated.type=basic
          - xpack.security.enabled=true
          - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
          - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
          - xpack.security.transport.ssl.client_authentication=required
          - xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path=elastic-certificates.p12
          - xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path=elastic-certificates.p12
      es02:
        image: es:${SERVICE_NAME}
        container_name: es02
        restart: unless-stopped
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: ./elk-config/elasticsearch/Dockerfile
          args:
            ELK_VERSION: ${ELK_VERSION:-7.13.3}
        networks:
          - ${NETWORK_NAME}
        volumes:
          - "${HOST_PATH}/elk/elasticsearch/es02/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:rw"
        ulimits:
          memlock:
            soft: -1
            hard: -1
        environment:
          - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
          - network.host=0.0.0.0
          - node.name=es02
          - discovery.seed_hosts=es02
          - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02
          - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m"
          - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
          - xpack.license.self_generated.type=basic
          - xpack.security.enabled=true
          - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
          - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
          - xpack.security.transport.ssl.client_authentication=required
          - xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path=elastic-certificates.p12
          - xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path=elastic-certificates.p12
      logstash:
        image: logstash:7.13.3
        container_name: logstash
        restart: unless-stopped
        networks:
          - ${NETWORK_NAME}
        volumes:
          - "./elk-config/logstash/:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline"
        environment:
          - SERVICE_NAME=${SERVICE_NAME}
          - NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
          - LOGSTASH_ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=${LOGSTASH_ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}
          - LOGSTASH_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=${LOGSTASH_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}
          - LOGSTASH_PORT=${LOGSTASH_PORT}
        depends_on:
          - es01
          - es02
      kibana:
        image: kibana:${SERVICE_NAME}
        build:
          context: ./elk-config/kibana/
          args:
            ELK_VERSION: ${ELK_VERSION:-7.13.3}
        container_name: kibana
        restart: unless-stopped
        networks:
          - ${NETWORK_NAME}
        volumes:
          - ./elk-config/kibana/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
          - ./elk-config/certs:/etc/kibana/config/certs
        environment:
          - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=${KIBANA_ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}
          - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=${KIBANA_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}
        depends_on:
          - es01
          - es02
          - logstash

networks:
  elk-network:
    name: ${NETWORK_NAME}
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.enable_ipv6: "false"
      com.docker.network.bridge.name: ${NETWORK_NAME}

kibana.yml
server:
  name: "elk"
  host: "0.0.0.0"
  port: 5601
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://es01:9200","http://es02:9200"]
monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled: true
csp.strict: true

logstash conf
input {
  tcp {
      port => "${LOGSTASH_PORT}"
  }
}

filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        index => "logs-${NODE_ENV}"
        hosts => ["http://es01:9200","http://es02:9200"]
        user => "${LOGSTASH_ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}"
        password => "${LOGSTASH_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}"
    }
}

htop metrics

How to find the reason of that CPU consumption?

Can you describe the usage of that cluster? What you are doing both at indexing level and search level? What is flowing through Logstash, how much?

@Val. Of course. We use it just for logs at the moment. But when I did the screenshot even the logs were not working. So it's the CPU usage without any process
